# метод шифрования php

Tags: php, ssl

нужно организовать обмен файлами между серверами, сохранение целостности файлов очень важно, т.к. в файлах будет php код, который подключается и выполняется. В php есть функция openssl_encrypt, но я заблудился в выборе варианта шифрования openssl_get_cipher_methods. Может кто в курсе какой вариант лучше выбрать? Интересует этот метод, т.к. его проще всего организовать, смотрел в сторону sftp, но кажется проще просто шифровать

Comment: Не проще ли подключить как удалённый каталог?

Comment: как это можно сделать? у меня винда

Comment: В винде не знаю, в linux делается элементарно. Возможно, вы вообще неправильно разработали архитектуру приложения. Обмен файлами (скриптами) - это жуткий архаизм

Comment: ну, на самом деле пока я планирую передачу массивов, т.е. зачем мне передавать файл в виде строк, потом парсить его в массив, если я могу сразу передать массив в файле? Может это не правильно, но по мне так очень даже практично, подумываю также из 1 источника подобным методом подключать функции, что с этим не так может быть? по 2-3 функции с разной степенью модификаций у меня сейчас есть - хорошего мало на самом деле.

Comment: Для передачи данных на сайт правильнее сделать REST сервис

Comment: у меня обмен данными между серверами, вы же не через рест подключаете файлы с функциями? так и тут то же самое, просто процессы на разных серверах, рест всё же немного про другое

Comment: Причём тут подключение файлов с функциями, если вы данные передаёте?

Comment: так я всегда данные передаю: с диска в озу, с озу на диск, поэтому я и спрашиваю - везде рест надо использовать? Как вы себе представляете подключение файла без передачи данных из него?

Comment: Зачем вам передавать файлы, если вам нужно передавать массив?

Comment: мне нужно передать файл, в котором массив, сохранить файл на другой стороне и затем подключить